# Python: ImportError no module named mysql.connector

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, importerror, mysql-connector-python

I just created an `exe` from `python` script and when I tried to run it, it did not show up.

Then, I tried to run it from `cmd` and I got `ImportError` below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkintertest2.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 
389, in load_module
  File "MySQL.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
Failed to execute script tkintertest2
```

How to solve this? I have installed `mysql.connector` using both `pip` install and `conda` install.

Comment: How did you create the exe with python? It's possible the modules were not placed into the exe file along with the script (possible $PATH issues). Have you verified that you can import mysql.connector in your python interpreter?

Comment: If there's a script file named `MySQL.py`, maybe rename `MySQL.py`.

Comment: @NuclearPeon I use pyinstaller to create the `exe`. I have tried to run the script before and it works fine.

Comment: @McGrady I've changed it just now and I tried to run the `exe` again, but still got the same error.

Comment: What command are you using to create the exe file using pyinstaller?

Comment: @NuclearPeon `pyinstaller scriptname.py`

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @garjted Based on your traceback, `Failed to execute script tkintertest2`, I'm assuming you are running a tk program that has a user interface of sorts. According to the docs here http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html?highlight=modules, a windowed application would be best suited to be created using this command: `pyinstaller –onefile –windowed myscript.py`

Comment: @garjted You might also try specifying mysql.connector in your pyinstaller script because mysql.connector is not listed in the list of supported modules it should bring in automatically. Perhaps the module discovery algorithm isn't picking it up. Try `pyinstaller --hidden-import mysql.connector myscript.py`

Comment: @Exprator you can see it in [here](https://github.com/jte0711/account-bank)

Comment: did you installed mysqlclient or mysql connector for python in your machine?

Comment: @NuclearPeon I tried the `pyinstaller –onefile –windowed myscript.py`, and when I double click it or run it from `cmd` a message box pop out showing `Failed to execute script tkintertest2` message. I'll try the latter.

Comment: @Exprator yes I did, I have mentioned it in the question that I use `pip` install at first then I install it again using `conda` install.

Comment: use this pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python @garjted

Comment: @NuclearPeon I tried it and it works! Thanks a lot! `pyinstaller --hidden-import mysql.connector myscript.py`

Comment: @garjted Excellent! I'll post it as the answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the pyinstaller docs [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html?highlight=hidden%20imports), pyinstaller is not finding the python module, so explicitly include it like so:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import mysql.connector myscript.py
```